# How to access a directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, filesystems

I would like to save image in a folder. I already the code. to download and save image but I would like to know how to find the path of ma folder !
I create a directory in xcode but the images don't find it and there aren't image in it.
So, I would like to save images in "img_bkgrd" folder.
[image]

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageName]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
```

to use the image I use this method:

```
-(UIImage *) loadImage:(NSString *)fileName inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath{
 UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directoryPath, fileName]];
 return result;
```

}

Can you send me the correct path ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save the images there. First of all, this is not actually a folder. It is called a **group**. It is a part of application bundle, which is readonly. You need to save data into `Documents` directory. Something like that:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *imageFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/img_bckr"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imageFolderPath])
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:imageFolderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

NSString* imagePath = [imageFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyImage"];

[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:imagePath options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
```

You may store `imagePath` somewhere or build it later based upon file name and then simply:

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Comment: thanks you very much, and how can I find and load the image ?-(UIImage *) loadImage:(NSString *)fileName inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath
{
     UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directoryPath, fileName]];
     return result;
}

Comment: I already use an Image name but the next line doesn't work: UIImage * image = [self loadImage:[DataModel instance].currentAirplane.name inDirectory:imagePath];

Comment: I have no idea what's inside loadImage: inDirectory:

Comment: It's the image name

Comment: no, it is a method name. and it is yours. it would be better if you post its code to your question

Comment: show the path that you use for saving and path for retrieving

Comment: Your paths are different most likely. Print them and see